# Codeigniter - Delete a record after 1 minute

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to get a function to run so that once a message has been posted to the database after say 1 minute it removes that row.

My database looks like this:

```
       CREATE TABLE `messages` (
       `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `user_id` int(35) NOT NULL,
       `account_number` int(25) NOT NULL,
       `message_content` text NOT NULL,
      `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `status` enum('1','0') NOT NULL,
       `txt` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Unread',
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
         ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Table for storing notifications/messages' AUTO_INCREMENT=27 ;
```

My current code looks like:

```
            $sql = "DELETE FROM messages WHERE created < DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 2 MINUTE )";
    $this->db->query($sql);
```

Basically like I said after 1/2 minutes this needs to remove the message from the database by the ID it's grabbing, how does one achieve this, because the code i have shown above isn't working. I am using ActiveRecord it that helps anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `DELETE` does not reference `ID`, so you will be deleting all messages regardless of the `ID`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to delete a single message by ID, a better strategy would be to have a periodic job like cron that deletes records at periodic intervals, or have another process other than your web server that performs deletions. Then you can flag the records that you want deleted, or pass the ID's to that process.

Does that help?

Comment: Not really mate, it's kinda like a facbook notification and after so many minutes after the user amends the message to read then it needs to remove that message after X amount of minutes (for testing purposes now I'm setting it to 1 min, but on a live server it will be set to 7 days)

Comment: So basically you need something like `last_updated_time`, and if that is older than your threshold (7 days or whatever), then the record should be deleted?

Comment: Yes something to that effect,, so using Codeigniter how will that happen?

Comment: CodeIgniter handles the front-end, what you need is a database trigger (or equivalent) to maintain the last updated time. I'm not familiar with MySQL in this regard, but it looks like you might already be doing that with the `created` field. Then you need a back-end process to periodically check and purge old records. You could run that process from a cron job to check every x minutes or hours. This could be a PHP file that is executed on behalf of cron, or a python script or whatever. Basically you just delete all records with a last updated time greater than your threshold.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to tackle this, depending on your access to your server.

1. Use MySQL events (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html). This will allow you to execute your sql query on i.e. each update of the table. You do however need "SUPER" permission on your database to use this.
2. Use `crontab`(unix) or a `scheduled task` (windows) to execute a php
   script containing your sql query every minute.
3. Put your sql query on the top of your page. This is ofcourse not perfect performance wise, but depending on how busy your site/application  or how big your database/table is, I doubt you'll notice the difference.

For reference: this sql will work:
`DELETE FROM messages WHERE created < (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 SECOND)`

Comment: The sql you said I tried that and i have changed my statement to say is the status is set to 0 which means the user has 'read' the message then remove it.    

     DELETE FROM messages WHERE status = '0' AND created < (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)

Comment: Ok.. but.. did it work ? :) If so, accept the answer (checkbox in front of the answer)